# Apply lambda involving 2 dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, intervals

I would like to select data in df2 based on time intervals in df1:

df1:

```
ID      Start                End                  col1   col2
23468   2011-01-03 01:01:03  2011-01-03 01:04:05  10     a
23468   2011-01-15 08:20:00  2011-01-18 01:01:01  50     b
23468   2011-02-03 01:07:20  2011-02-08 12:00:03  150    a
33525   2011-02-03 01:07:19  2011-02-06 12:00:03  10     a
                      ...
```

df2:

```
ID     Timestap             col3   col4
23468  2011-01-03 01:01:03  3     aa
23468  2011-01-03 01:02:00  4     bb
23468  2011-01-03 12:01:03  7     aa
33525  2011-02-03 02:31:03  10    aa
33525  2011-02-04 12:01:03  20    aa
33525  2011-02-05 14:00:01  30    aa
                      ...
```

I need to filter `df2` if `ID` matches that in `df1` and `Timestamp` is in between `Start` and `End` in `df1`, then calculate the average of `col3` of the group and create a new column in `df1` called `Average`, expected output:

```
ID      Start                End                  col1   col2   Average
23468   2011-01-03 01:01:03  2011-01-03 01:04:05  10     a      3.5
23468   2011-01-15 08:20:00  2011-01-18 01:01:01  50     b      nan
23468   2011-02-03 01:07:20  2011-02-08 12:00:03  150    a      nan
                      ...

33525   2011-02-03 01:07:19  2011-02-06 12:00:03  10     a      20
                      ...
```

I tried using a for-loop but it takes ages as the **dataframes are too large and merging two dataframes will take even longer**, I am wondering if `apply()` with lambda expression can solve this issue? How do I refer to time intervals from another df?

---

Update:
What if I want to filter `df2` based on time intervals in `df1`, then find the difference between the first and last `col3`(ie. 6-3 =3), divide this value by the difference between the first and last `Timestamp`(ie. 2011-01-03 01:03:03 - 2011-01-03 01:01:03 = 120 seconds). So expected value is `3/120=0.025`.

df1:

```
ID      Start                End                  col1   col2
23468   2011-01-03 01:01:03  2011-01-03 01:04:05  10     a     (*)
23468   2011-01-15 08:20:00  2011-01-18 01:01:01  50     b
23468   2011-02-03 01:07:20  2011-02-08 12:00:03  150    a
33525   2011-02-03 01:07:19  2011-02-06 12:00:03  10     a
                      ...
```

df2:

```
ID     Timestap             col3   col4
23468  2011-01-03 01:01:03  3     aa   first row in time interval (*)
23468  2011-01-03 01:02:00  4     bb
23468  2011-01-03 01:03:03  6     aa   last row in time interval (*)   
23468  2011-01-03 12:01:03  7     aa
33525  2011-02-03 02:31:03  10    aa
33525  2011-02-04 12:01:03  20    aa
33525  2011-02-05 14:00:01  30    aa
```

So the expected output:

```
ID      Start                End                  col1   col2   Average
23468   2011-01-03 01:01:03  2011-01-03 01:04:05  10     a      0.025       (3/120=0.025)
23468   2011-01-15 08:20:00  2011-01-18 01:01:01  50     b      nan
23468   2011-02-03 01:07:20  2011-02-08 12:00:03  150    a      nan
                      ...

33525   2011-02-03 01:07:19  2011-02-06 12:00:03  10     a 0.000067032     (20/298364 =0.000067032)    
                      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list generator, it is several times faster than a loop.
In rows 2, it should be 20 if I'm not mistaken.
df1.iloc on the left are row indices, on the right are column numbers. In df2, explicit indexing is used: on the left is a boolean mask as indexes (True or False), on the right is the name of the column.

```
import pandas as pd

df1[['Start', 'End']] = df1[['Start', 'End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2['Timestap'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestap'])

aaa = [df2.loc[(df2['Timestap'] >= df1.iloc[i, 1])
               & (df2['Timestap'] <= df1.iloc[i, 2]), 'col3'].mean() for i in range(len(df1))]

df1['Average'] = aaa
print(df1)
```

Output

```
      ID               Start                 End  col1 col2  Average
0  23468 2011-01-03 01:01:03 2011-01-03 01:04:05    10    a      3.5
1  23468 2011-01-15 08:20:00 2011-01-18 01:01:01    50    b      NaN
2  23468 2011-02-03 01:07:20 2011-02-08 12:00:03   150    a     20.0
3  33525 2011-02-03 01:07:19 2011-02-06 12:00:03    10    a     20.0
```

**Update 26.08.2022.**
We write the indexes of matching rows from df2 into the df1['123'] column.

In 'ind', copy the indices where greater than or equal to two in each rows.

'qqq' get the difference between the last and first element of each row.

'ttt' difference in seconds.

'tq' we get what we need and store it in the df1['test'] column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1[['Start', 'End']] = df1[['Start', 'End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2['Timestap'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestap'])

df1['123'] = [df2.loc[(df2['Timestap'] >= df1.iloc[i, 1])
                      & (df2['Timestap'] <= df1.iloc[i, 2]), 'col3'].values for i in range(len(df1))]

ind = df1[df1['123'].str.len().ge(2)].index
qqq = df1.loc[ind, '123'].str[-1] - df1.loc[ind, '123'].str[0]
ttt = (df1.loc[ind, 'End'] - df1.loc[ind, 'Start']) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
tq = qqq / ttt
df1['test'] = tq

print(df1)
```

Output

```
      ID               Start                 End  ...  col2           123      test
0  23468 2011-01-03 01:01:03 2011-01-03 01:04:05  ...     a     [3, 4, 6]  0.016484
1  23468 2011-01-15 08:20:00 2011-01-18 01:01:01  ...     b            []       NaN
2  23468 2011-02-03 01:07:20 2011-02-08 12:00:03  ...     a  [10, 20, 30]  0.000042
3  33525 2011-02-03 01:07:19 2011-02-06 12:00:03  ...     a  [10, 20, 30]  0.000067
```

Comment: Hi inquier thanks for your answer. Due to the different time interval, I realized I have to use `(last col3- first col3)/(last timestamp- first timestamp)` instead of using `.mean()`. Would you know how I can do that (something like an aggregation as opposed to `.mean()`)?

Comment: @nilsinelabore show the expected result to avoid guessing.

Comment: Hi inquirer please see question update